# Creating an event with POST /users/{meeting room email}/events responds 201 without performing a conflict check

Tags: outlook-restapi

My team is working on an app where we are experimenting with creating an event directly on a meeting room's primary calendar like `POST https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/users/{meeting room email}/events`, and pending a successful response, subsequently PATCHing the event with the desired attendees. However, I've found that I invariably get a 201 even if the meeting room has a conflicting event. Is there a way to get the API to tell me synchronously if there is a conflict? We are trying to avoid the case where you create the event as a real user with the room as an attendee and get a success, only to find that the room auto-rejects the invitation some seconds later.